# Code block executed when script starts before '__main__'

Tags: python

Is there a way to specify a code block in Python to be executed when the script starts before `__main__` with its declared variables visible to all subsequent members without being passed (something like a script-level scope)?

Comment: Everything before `if __name__ == "__main__"` **is** executed upon import. If you need a more specific section of code, then import just functions, not the whole module

Comment: @OneCricketeer you can make that an answer

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. `__name__` is a variable which matches `"__main__"`. There is code that executes before **`__name__`** gets set. Are you trying to edit this? Perhaps you can share a [mcve] of what you want?